# FTP files from folders that have international characters/mutations/vowels (ä. ö. ü) with Windows FTP in batch-file

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I'm trying to create a batch file that uploads files to an FTP server. It all works fine except for one specific folder which has mutations/vowels in its name (can't change that. Aka the folders name has an `ö` inside. ).

My question here is: What options exist to achieve this?

Example for the `ftp` batch file (UTF-8 encoding):

```
cd C:\uplaodfiles\ländle\*
ftp -n -s:C:\test\UploadTest.ftp
```

Example for the loaded file:

```
open meimei
user meiuser meipassword
pasv
bin
cd uploaddir
prompt
mput c:\uploadfiles\ländle\*
close
bye
```

It all works until the `mput` where the `ftp` tries to convert the `ä` into special characters that the local drive naturally does not find.

As additional note: I start out in the `c:\test` folder on the command line as the `UploadTest.bat` file is located there.....even though I use `cd`. thus if I use `mput` without parameters (or with only `*` given) it is still `c:\test` which he copies.

Edit:

The output from a run (I cut out the non important parts..... `pasv` fails btw. No clue why? Had showed it previously so I'm leaving that part out).

```
ftp> BIN
200 Command okay.
ftp> cd uploaddir
250 CWD command successful.
ftp> prompt
Interaktivmodus AUS .              <-- interactive mode off
ftp> mput C:\L├ñndle\*             <-- should be Ländle
C:\L├ñndle\*:Datei nicht gefunden  <-- file not found
ftp> close
221 Service closing control connection.
ftp> bye
```

*As a bit of it is in German I've put in translations where necessary with <--*

Comment: Try "OPTS UTF8 ON" so ftp client and server agree to use UTF-8 encoded names

Comment: this specific target ftp server seemingly does not know the opts command (just tried it and then looked at the command list)

Comment: tar/zip, ftp and untar/unzip is one option, Using Perl or Python ftp modules is another

Comment: what would tar/zip bring if I can't go even to the folder? (because of the vowels/mutations) as also the lc command fails.

Comment: Oh, ok, going to the parent folder of the folder with mutations and tar/zip from there also doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried Windows 7 with an ANSI (Microsoft proprietay) encoded file? Find the local codepage using the `CHCP` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works, as long as the `UploadTest.ftp` is either

- in UTF-8 encoding (with or without BOM) – Windows 10 only (didn't test Windows 8)
- in ANSI encoding that matches the Windows *"Language for non-Unicode programs"* and the characters in the file name are contained in the ANSI encoding – Windows 7 and 10

The UTF-8 in batch files does not seem to be supported (both in Windows 7 and Windows 10). So you cannot do the `cd` there (unless in the default legacy ANSI encoding).

---

If you need a UTF-8 solution for Windows 7, you probably have to use another FTP client.

For example with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting):

- Batch file:

  ```
  winscp.com /log=UploadTest.log /script=UploadTest.ftp
  ```
- Upload script (`UploadTest.ftp`) in UTF-8 encoding with BOM:

  ```
  open ftp://meiuser:meipassword@meimei/
  cd uploaddir
  put c:\uploadfiles\ländle\*
  exit
  ```

See the guide for [Converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: yes the plain windows ftp.exe. I'm using the pasv command as it was mentioned in one example that I should do it if I use one of the commands I use (and when connected "?"  showed that). Will  try to see about the encoding in a bit. Windows 7 here

Comment: The encoding of the .ftp file is UTF8-without BOM (according to notepad++). Same for the .bat file

Comment: Can it be that your ftp server is configured to accept utf-8 symbols? (that its a problem not form the client but the server side?. As its an external ftp server where I'm connecting to I can't check its configuration so have to ask there)

Comment: Show us the output of the `ftp.exe`, so that we can tell if it is a local or remote problem.

Comment: Also show us the output of the `?`. I do not have any `pasv` there.

Comment: Did you try to upload the (whole) folder using GUI FTP client like WinSCP or FileZilla?

Comment: updating the question in a min. Interestingly pasv fails (although ? listed it previously). So I take it as a display or misread error on my part. I tried it out with FileZilla and there its no problem if I do things manually and the vowels/mutations are displayed correctly.

Comment: Indeed it does not work on Windows 7 with UTF-8. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Microsoft has updated ftp.exe? But my experiences are somewhat different from those of @Martin Prikryl:

- Windows 10 (1903): UploadTest.ftp can be UTF-8 encoded, with or without BOM
- Windows 7: UploadTest.ftp can be UTF-8 encoded, **BOM must not exist**
- Windows XP (!): UploadTest.ftp can be UTF-8 encoded, **BOM must not exist**

Tested with characters ä, ö, ü, and ᚠ.

**Edit 1:** The alternative to UTF-8 is an ASCII file encoded with ANSI codepage (ACP) but not OEM codepage (OEMCP) of the machine.

**Edit 2:** If you want to use stdout of the ftp.exe process, the encoding of stdout has to be ASCII with OEM codepage (tested unter Windows 10 only)! What a typical MS mess!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My batch file is generated by a VBScript, and its coded in UTF-8. The solution was converting the file to ANSI. You can try converting your batch and testint. If it works, you can use the code in https://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/misc/text/utf8_ansi.asp

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29777226)